# Suggested question scores do not line up with their titles

Tags: bug, asking-questions, meta, design, duplicate-suggestions

The alignment of items in the block *Questions that may already have your answer* is weird. The first question score is shown before the question and subsequent question and scores doesn't match. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the problem describe]

Right now, I'm using Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m, but it looks the same on Internet Explorer. Reproduced on Firefox 22.0

Edit: Stack Overflow looks normal.

Comment: Yep, same here.

Comment: Reproduced. Eeek!

Comment: Repro with IE 10.0.9200.16484 on WinRT. SO looks normal for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we're testing ripping out most of the MVC view template stacking here on Meta for more speed, you found the second bug we've encountered - thanks!

I've disabled the optimized rendering for now, Monty will take a look when he's in and get a permenant fix out.  It's a fairly substantial performance improvement on any html rendering when many small views are involved, otherwise we wouldn't be doing such crazy things.

Oh who am I kidding, we'd just be doing *other* crazy things.