# Number of votes display changed on MSO

Tags: bug, asking-questions, flag-history, similar-questions

The votes display for one-liner display has changed on meta Stack Overflow. It doesn't look so good when it is on the similar questions list of *Ask Question* page, but is perfect for the flag summary page. The screen-caps:

[image: flag summary]

and

[image: similar questions]

As can be seen from the above screenshots; it isn't so consistent on the "ask Questions" page. I know you guys might still be fiddling around with it, I just thought I'd leave a mention of the fact here as well. :)

Comment: I don't know about your first screenshot, but it seems you're reporting this bug?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194050/problem-when-im-typing-the-question-title-in-the-questions-suggested Making this a dupe?

Comment: @Bart Yeah, the second one is as reported on that thread. The flag-summary [used to be concise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TA39i.png).

Comment: Okay, I'll leave this open then, assuming the first one is a different issue.

Comment: You really like the new flag summary better? I don't. I prefer [the original](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TA39i.png). I think this is all the same bug.